# UIImagePickerController with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS in ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiimagepickercontroller, exc-bad-access

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePicker.delegate = self;
imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imagePicker.allowsEditing = YES;
[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This code make crash EXC_BAD_ACCESS on ios7 devices.
On iOS6 - all okay, and UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary work normal.

Comment: give more info... and post all crash report

Comment: @user1180489 most probably you are try to access camera in simulator itself. Simulate don't have camera. So you need to check sourcetypecamera is available or not.

Comment: No, i test on device.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To work with camera

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
     UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    UIImagePickerController* imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePickerController.delegate = self;
    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                        (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                        (NSString *) kUTTypeMovie, nil];
    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];    }
```

Comment: [self presentModalViewController...] is deprecated, edit with [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: @Ilario Thanks to notify.